# функция fetch повторно не отправляет запрос

Tags: javascript, nginx, cors

Помогите, пожалуйста, с такой проблемой. Пытаюсь отправить кроссдоменный запрос c помощью [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
 send(url, params, header) {
    var headers = header || {};
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(params),
        mode:'cors'
    };

    return  Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch(url, options));
}
```

nginx настроен так, что отдаёт 200 статус по OPTIONS, а в заголовках отправляет, какие методы открыты. Но браузер не отправляет второй запрос. Его надо отправлять в ручную.

Так же получаю ошибку когда отправляю POST

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

**Вопрос 1**: Как добиться  того, чтобы отправлялся второй запрос после ответа OPTION ?

**Вопрос 2**: Почему возвращается No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' если он установлен в 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *. Может это связано 404 статусом?

Ответ от сервера по OPTIONS http://prntscr.com/fmb04u

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**. Конфиг nginx http://prntscr.com/fmpr9s

Comment: а что сервер отдает по POST? Если настройки только для OPTIONS - то вполне логично следующее падение

Comment: @Grundy отдаёт http://prntscr.com/fmb8lt. Ага,  не вижу 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *. Это из за этого?

Comment: Это в принципе логично. Данный заголовок должен добавляться для всех нужных методов, а не только для OPTIONS

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за помощь. А не знаете почему fetch второй раз не не отправляет запрос? В Angular2 сначала OPTIONS отправляется потом один из методов  GET, POST... А сейчас необходимо второй раз отправлять fetch что бы он постом отправил.

Comment: Собственно никто и не заставляет слать OPTIONS, можешь слать POST сразу.

Comment: @Grundy А что бы сразу слать можно сделать fetch API или надо обычный XMLHttpRequest делать?

Comment: @МирославРоманчук что угодно. Отличаются только способом отправки данных, данные придут одни и те же.

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz  Просто я почему спрашиваю у меня в данном примере fetch сначала отправляет на OPTIONS автоматически.  Как можно говорить fetch что бы он сразу допустим на POST отправлял?

Comment: Поставил no-cors и вроде шлёт сразу на пост, но не уверен можно ли кросдоменный запрос сделать с mode: no-cors?

Comment: Покажите конфиг nginx. Вынгую нехватку флага `always ` у add_header

Comment: @AlexeyTen вот конфиг  http://prntscr.com/fmpr9s, это заголовок в header должен быть?

Comment: Прекратите выкладывать код скриншотами и прочитайте внимательно документацию по add_headers